# libgconf-2-4 refuses to install. How can I fix this?

Tags: kali-linux, package-management

I’m running Kali Linux, release version 2023.4.

`libgconf-2-4` refuses to install, but I need it to install `spotify-client` following the "Debian/Ubuntu" section of [these instructions](https://www.spotify.com/de-en/download/linux/)).

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have a small script set up that follows the specific instructions on the spotify website. I recently had to reinstall my OS due to a screwup that occurred (still not sure what happened there). The script worked before the reinstall. I've compared the script to the spotify website, it's still a match, but after the reinstall two days back, I've had nothing but problems in general. I'm slowly working through them, most of them are very easy fixes, but this one is giving me grief.

Comment: Using an old installation stick for a rolling distribution like Kali isn’t reliable in general. If you want to stick with Kali, you should really use a recent installation image. As others have said, other distributions might be more appropriate for you.

Answer (score -1):

**WARNING: USING THE FOLLOWING "DPKG" COMMAND WITHOUT FULLY UNDERSTANDING IT'S EFFECTS HAS THE POTENTIAL TO BREAK YOUR ENTIRE SYSTEM.**

*NOTE 1: If you run "`apt --fix-missing --fix-broken install`" with or without specifying a package, any packages install using the following method may be removed in the process, but can be reinstalled through the same method if desired.*

NOTE 2: "spotify-client" and "spotify*" can be replaced with the names of the packages relevant to your needs.

`apt download spotify-client`

`dpkg --force-all -i spotify`

Comment: Note that one of the effects of this is to prevent future upgrades to the system.

Comment: It also means that if spotify actually needs any of the functionality in gconf at some point in its operation, it might crash in very ugly ways. I'm not even sure I'd count this as an answer…